# Extreme verbosity with MySQL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am having an issue and can't resolve it after spending a lot of time on Google:

The call to DriverManager.getConnection() inside a Java program prints a thousand lines like this to stdout:

Wed Nov 21 10:00:41 CET 2018 TRACE:       --> TRACE_MESSAGE

How can I remove this trace output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your StackTrace?

Comment: Do you use some logging library like Log4j?

Comment: Change your logging config to not log TRACE level log messages? TRACE level message are usually pretty verbose because they are for tracing problems.

Comment: @Abhinav There is no stack trace. At least not in a usual Java manner. The kind of trace is the one specified in the post, which I haven't seen in my life.

Comment: @HélioMárcioFilho I am not using any logging library. I using one the only way to not print these messages?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Where should I change my logging configuration. After searching a lot I haven't found where to touch.

Comment: @JohnDoe Where are your thousand lines? Would you mind to post that in your question?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, by default the driver will not MySQL driver will not log trace level events unless you explicitly configured it to. What is you connection config and which version of the driver do you use?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks Mark! It was an issue with the version.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved. I was using JDBC 5.0.8. I switched to 8.0.13 and everything ran smoothly. My Java version is openjdk 10.0.2.

Thanks for all the comments!